# Win 8.1 Universal app - App Exit on Fast App Switching

Tags: wpf, mvvm, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am developing an app for Windows Universal 8.1, facing an issue where the App gets Exit on going background. The scenarios are as follows

1. When the app goes background on clicking Windows key(FAS), the app get exit.
2. When I launch Share Task i.e Data Transfer Manager Interface, after completing the share operation the app exit.

Works fine in Debug mode but issue found after deploying to the device.

PS : I am using the Navigation Service Interface to navigate to pages using MVVM and navigating from viewmodels.

Please help if its known issue, if not help to rectify this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your App crashes in The **Suspending** Event. As apps in Debug mode are not suspended, you are unlikely to see that happen.

You can manually fire the event from Visual Studio when debugging: It is in the debugging toolbar under *Application Lifecycle Events*.

Most common error in this case: Using complex objects as navigation parameters, which cannot be serialized.

Comment: Thanks.. You are absolutely right. I checked using Lifecycle events. It is serialisation issue. It means I need to serialise the object to string and pass sthe string as parameter right?

Comment: Either that or just pass simple types (like an ID) and get you actual dara from some service using that id.